# How do you use setId in android?

Tags: android, textview

I setup this loop, and it works fine, but I would like to be able to change each textView individually, so I need to setup textView.setId(whateveryouputinhere); Could someone please explain to me how to setup the id and what you put inside the parenthesis? Thanks!

```
while (counter < 5) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.newplayerlayout, null);
            parent.addView(view); 
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            textView.setText("Player "+counter);
            textView.setId(counter);
            counter++;

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I setup this loop, and it works fine, but I would like to be able to change each textView individually

ok

> so I need to setup textView.setId(whateveryouputinhere);

no you don't, there are better ways to achieve what you are trying to do.

One example might be something like this:

```
LayoutInflator mInflator; //You are creating 5 of these with your code, you don't need to.
mInflator = LayoutInflater.from(this); //Your activity is a context. So you pass it in, instead 
                                       //calling getBaseContext(). Which you should try avoid generally.
TextView[] mTxts = new TextView[5](this);
while (counter < 5) {
    mTxts[counter] = (TextView)mInflator.inflate(R.layout.newplayerlayout, null);
    parent.addView(view); 
    //TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    //You don't need this any more.

    mTxts[counter].setText("Player "+counter);
    //textView.setId(counter);
    //don't need this either.
    counter++;
}
//Now that your array is loaded you can set the text like this:
mTxts[0].setText("plums");
mTxts[2].setText("grapes");
```

Note, I didn't compile this but it should be close. If you get an error on the "this" change them to "YourActivity.this" with the name of your activity class.

There are a few benefits, by keeping the LayoutInflater reference you save creating 4 more of those. After you inflate the view object there is no need to then find it by Id, you've already got it. You can cast it as a TextView right out of the inflater if you like. By keeping them in an array you can always reference each of them without having to call findViewById() again, this method is rather expensive, you should try to avoid calling it excessively.

Comment: I'm getting a error at TextView[] it says: `Syntax error on token "]", AssignmentOperator expected after this token - The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable`

Answer (score 0):

According to [`View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId%28int%29) documentation,

> The identifier does not have to be unique in this view's hierarchy. The identifier should be a positive number.

In this case there can be some views with equivalent id's. If you want to search for some view in hierarchy calling to `setTag` with some key objects may be handy.

Comment: So if I used textView.setId(counter); how would I call on that id later, would I use view.findViewById(1);? if I was trying to access the first textView I made?

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind that `findViewById()` will return the first `View` with the given id it finds. Just because ids don't have to be unique, it doesn't mean you shouldn't be aware of it (or else you'll run into trouble later on).

Comment: It might be smart to define these ids in a static XML file instead.

Comment: Sweet! That worked, Thanks! I dont know how many textViews theirs going to be until its entered into the app, so pre defining them in the xml wouldn't work.

Comment: you really should solve this problem without need all of the calls to findViewById().